# Switch case doesn't work. Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to use switch. It works for all the cases except for one which has absolutely no difference with the others.

It tests the remaining from the division by 13 of the first array(int) and depending on that assigns specific values to the second one(Char).

```
 public static char[] FindValue(int[] OCards) {
    char[] OValue = new char[5];
    int n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        n = OCards[i] % 13;
        switch (n) {
            case 0:
                OValue[i] = 'A';
                break;
            case 1:
                OValue[i] = '2';
                break;
            case 2:
                OValue[i] = '3';
                break;
            case 3:
                OValue[i] = '4';
                break;
            case 4:
                OValue[i] = '5';
                break;
            case 5:
                OValue[i] = '6';
                break;
            case 6:
                OValue[i] = '7';
                break;
            case 7:
                OValue[i] = '8';
                break;
            case 8:
                OValue[i] = '9';
                break;
            case 9:
                OValue[i] = '10'; //Error here 'unclosed character literal'
                break;
            case 10:
                OValue[i] = 'V';
                break;
            case 11:
                OValue[i] = 'D';
                break;
            case 12:
                OValue[i] = 'R';
                break;


        }
    }
    return OValue;
}
```

Comment: A character literal can only contain exactly 1 character.  `10` are two characters.

Comment: Can a character literal be more than one character?

Comment: How is `10` a single character??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, the problem is that `'10'` isn't a *character*.

We can solve this, and at the same time save your finger a lot of bending:

```
n = OCards[i] % 13;
OValue[i] = "A23456789TVDR".charAt(n);
```

That one line replaces your entire `switch` statement.

I'm not certain of the right symbol to use, though. In English, it would be a `T`. But in French, you clearly can't use `D` for both *dame* and *dix*.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot.
You're right, i'll use T and if it's not good enough, i'll change T to 10 when outputting the cards.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is because you are trying to make a char with two characters, and you can only make a char with one.

You'll want to change your array to store ints, or as it is commonly done if you need to store char's, with 'T' or 't'.

Answer (score 1):

`Ovalue` is an array of `char`s; `'10'` isn't a *single* character.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
  case 9:
            OValue[i] = 'T'; //use T char to stand for 10
            break
```